# xkb: How to turn a symbols file into a working keymap?

Tags: xkb

My goal is to create a keyboard map that I can switch via the GUI (here gnome on Ubuntu 19.10, but I have also tried with Xfce and got the same problem, so I am assuming this is xkb rather than Gnome/Xfce related).

Process:

I've placed a symbols file in `/usr/share/x11/kbd/symbols`, let's call it enT. (The file is available here https://github.com/bjohas/Ubuntu-keyboard-map-like-OS-X/blob/master/maps/enT, but I believe the actual content of the file makes no difference, hence not reproduced here.)

I can change the keyboard layout by using

```
setxkbmap enT
```

which works as expected.

I've also added a variant entry referring to enT to evdev.xml, which means that the map now appears in the GUI as an available keyboard map. However, when I select the map from the GUI, it doesn't work.

My suspicion is that just placing the new map into `/usr/share/x11/kbd/symbols` and making the change to evdev.xml isn't sufficient, but that I perhaps need to create a fuller description and place that somewhere?

E.g. is there something I should be doing with the output of `setxkbmap enT -print`, which gives?

```
xkb_keymap {
    xkb_keycodes  { include "evdev+aliases(qwerty)" };
    xkb_types     { include "complete"  };
    xkb_compat    { include "complete"  };
    xkb_symbols   { include "pc+enT+inet(evdev)"    };
    xkb_geometry  { include "pc(pc105)" };
};
```

Any help appreciated!

Comment: You did not mention `xkbcomp`.

Comment: Thanks - I've seen xkbcomp, but I'm not quite sure what to do with the output it generates... how does that work?

Comment: I only tested it once, It looks like it depends what the target is. Both man pages (setxkbmap and xkbcomp) talk about how they can work together. `setxkbmap us -print | xkbcomp - $DISPLAY` is a special case but it shows the two steps. https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/546630/keyboard-mapping....here I got 100 bonus point. for nothing much, just to give you an impression what to expect on XKB questions here.

Comment: Thank you - that's  helpful. How does it help with GUI-based switching? Instead of piping to xkbcomp, should the output be stored somewhere?